# SSIS tasks executing in the wrong order

Tags: ssis

I have a package with 4 Execute SQL tasks and a data flow task.

[image: SSIS Task Sequence]

The sequence is defined using precedence constraints and should be:

1. (SQL) Create table (if not exists)
2. (SQL) Create backup table
3. (SQL) backup and clear
4. (DF) Import teams data
5. (SQL) Remove stale data

However, it runs in the order 3, 2, 1, 5, 4.

I read on the net that this can be solved by deleting the tasks and adding again in the order of execution, so I did this but the result is exactly the same!

What else can I do to fix it?

[Edit]

SQL version is:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

[/Edit]

[Update]

SSIS package "SERVICEAREATEAMS.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0209303 at New Package, Connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDB_NOPROVIDER_64BIT_ERROR.  The requested OLE DB provider OraOLEDB.Oracle.1 is not registered -- perhaps no 64-bit provider is available.  Error code: 0x00000000.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".
Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task 1, Source - Query [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfIdG.png): SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionOLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: component "Source - Query" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task 1, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "SERVICEAREATEAMS.dtsx" finished: Failure.

[/Update]

[Update 2]

[image: Results in different sequence to design]

[/Update 2]

Comment: In 7 years of working with SSIS, I have never seen that happen. Could you point me to the links you used that talked about the issue and the resolution of recreating the precedence constraints?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255454/can-ssis-execute-tasks-in-specific-order See second answer

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2005, 2008 or 2008 R2? What the patch level of the machine you are executing the packages on? `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')` Does it provide the same behaviour if executed from BIDS/Visual Studio?

Comment: 2008 R2 (RTM). If executed from VS it seems to run in the right order but the data Flow task throws an exception (see update), even though there is no error when run using the Execute Package Utility.

Comment: I think this exception is a red herring though, more to do with Oracle drivers and not being able to find a 64 bit one. However in real life, only a 32 bit one is available so this is the one needed for the package.

Comment: Ok so I created a new package with 2 tasks and then added a package task (see Update 2). You can clearly see that the output shows that the third task executed first. I would really appreciate some help here...

Comment: Actually thats not true. The tasks execute in the right order, but the output is in the wrong order (look at the times!). Why is this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why would yo usay it runs on that order? I can assure you that, based on your print screen, thre is no way task 3 is runnig before task 1.

If you think that because the way you see the output (your last screen), you are looking at it the wrong way. It doesnt show the order the tasks are executed, it shows each task individually (I even think they are ordered alfabetically). Also be aware on the type of task, you have the `PREPARE` of sql task 1 finishing at 13:57:04 and the `EXECUTE` of the pacakge at 13:57:06, whihc seems to be on the right order to me

Comment: Yup that's what I noticed (see last comment of first answer) but thanks :)

Comment: ok, but its not that the output is on the wrong order, this is the way it is meant to be (it may be "wrong" from a logical point of view, but this is not an issue with you, its like this withe everybody)

Comment: True. I have no idea why I was expecting it to be in a logical order. What's wrong with me?? Thanks for the update.